# finding index of rows in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

i have a  matrix B of `N*3` dim. I want to find the indices of B whose column `3` has value `1`.

I used the command `[~,id]=ismember(1,B(:,3))`. `id` returns only value 1 even though there are many rows in the matrix which has the column 3 with value 1. Can any one point out what is wrong in the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather do:

```
id = find(B(:,3)==1)
```

but as an aside, to use `ismember` you should swap your input `[~,id]=ismember(B(:,3),1)`.